# How do I use apfs-fuse to mount a Mac hard drive using an Ubuntu live session?

Tags: live-usb, fuse

I want to access my files on my Mac (APFS) using Ubuntu live USB.

I used Cubic (to install `apfs-fuse`) to make the live USB.

I followed this [guide](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2020/11/13/step-by-step-apfs-fuse-ubuntu-20-04-installation/3/) (this is the last page), but nothing happened. I couldn't mount the Mac partition.

The guide was meant for an installed system, but I thought I would try my luck with live USB anyway.

I got this "options" menu after entering the last command in the guide :

```
sudo apfs-fuse -o allow_other /dev/sda2 /media/$USERNAME/macos
```

[image: Screenshot]

I don't know what to do since I am new to using Linux.

I would appreciate it if someone could make a guide for my particular purpose (live USB)..

Comment: Did you really use `/media/$USERNAME/macos` as the mount path? Your screenshot appears to show `/media/ubuntu/New` (possibly with additional characters cut off) - did you try to use a path containing whitespace (like `/media/ubuntu/New folder`)?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes My path is "New Volume" actually...

Comment: @Nmath hmm ..Did not know that..

Comment: @hosa and did you remember to quote it (or escape the space)? otherwise `apfs-fuse` will see `Volume` as a separate parameter

Comment: @steeldriver I DID NOT do any of this, okay im sorry for my ignorance but please tell me what to do exactly..

Comment: @Nmath I now got the idea that I will copy and paste text and transfer via usb next time because im on another computer.. (The wlan is broken on my first laptop)

Comment: ... for example `"/media/ubuntu/New Volume"` or `/media/ubuntu/New\ Volume` (however there may be other APFS-specific issues as @Nmath has pointed out - I have no experience with that)

Comment: @steeldriver okay ill try that tomorrow and see the results, pausing for now..

Comment: Hey, Im back again, sorry I was too busy for this side project.. Just like you said, I got the error "This doesn't seem to be an apfs volume (invalid superblock) unable to load container" So unfortunately it seems that everything comes to a halt until there is a viable solution..

Comment: -[continued]- ^ its not technically possible without putting the HD in an Apple computer and mine is a Macbook Air (probably too hard to consider it)...